# USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR only to selected fields of a model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `model` which has a field price-FloatField, but as we know there is one more field automatically generated in DB- ID. I only want my price to be comma separated using `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` in `django`.

When I use `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR= True` in my `settings.py` file it changes both ID and price to be comma-separated.

Also, 
I have used `NUMBER_GROUPING=2`, but it still groups it with 3 numbers.

for e.g : I have prices like 2100- I want it to be 2,100 and 1000000 to be 10,00,000. For id field if it is 1700- it should remain 1700.

But in my case it is showing id 1700 to 1,700 which i don't require.
and for price it is showing 1,000,000 instead of 10,00,000.

Lastly if this all is not possible , how can I use

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ my_num|intcomma }}
```

What should be `my_num` in my case? If I keep it price(name of my model field) it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, which type of output you want, can you please provide some example in your question?

Comment: in your case, it should be your price.

Comment: If you will use intcomma it wil seprate your number 1000000 to be 1,000,000 and your required number format is 10,00,000.

Comment: If I keep it price , it is not working.

Comment: price is Float filed?

Comment: Did you added `django.contrib.humanize` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: @MKPatel yes, and price is float field

Comment: Please try it `{{ my_num|intcomma:False }}`